# Pass command line arguments to OOB Silverlight 4 application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, out-of-browser

I need to launch a Silverlight 4 OOB app through an existing WinForms application (using `System.Diagnostics.Process` to execute `sllauncher.exe`). I was hoping there would be some way to make `sllauncher.exe` accept and pass on command line args to the OOB application, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's not an API provided by Silverlight to gain access to the command-line arguments.

This is where WPF (and maybe click-once) would be a better option.

Or consider storing the "data" needed to be passed in a local file accessible by the Silverlight application when it starts.

Answer (score 3):

You can work around this by passing an URL to `sllauncher.exe`'s `/origin` parameter, e.g.:

`sllauncher.exe /overwrite /emulate:c:\temp\Hello.xap /origin:c:\temp\Hello.xap?key=value`.

In your Silverlight code, you can access the value of the `/origin` parameter via

```
Application.Current.Host.Source.OriginalString 
// file:///C:/temp/Hello.xap%3Fkey=value
```

(msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.silverlighthost.source(v=vs.96).aspx)

Unfortunately, because the URI is a `file:///` URI, the query parameters are not stored in `Source.QueryString`. This might also create opportunities, however, for "abuse" - my limited experience is that `sllauncher` will start if what is passed to `/origin` *somewhat* looks like a path or URI.

Answer (score 0):

yah its possible in silverlight

```
dynamic cmd=AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Shell.Application");
cmd.ShellExecute(@path_of_ur_exe,null,null,null,1);
```